# I can't find main.xml in a exciting code where i can put the Banner Ads code

Tags: android, xml

The issue:

Am now Make some Re-skinning on exciting code and am following the documentation attached with the purchased code. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't containing the ''Incorporation Google Mobile Ads into app''
I try to follow the instructions in developers Google Website.

to this point all the things are OK but when I came to Add an AD banner especially in the :

> > Create your banner in XML Section

They say Define a com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView in res/layout/main.xml.

But i found that my code not containing a main.xml.

Screenshot:

http://www.shy22.com/upfilpng/o2h28564.png

I try to create a new xml file and call it Main.xml automatically another file display to me here is:

http://www.shy22.com/upfilpng/dus28564.png

Any help plz

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an xml file in your layout folder called "main.xml".  This should have NO capital letters.

Also, if you're in Eclipse, you can try Refactor->Move, to put it in the correct location.

Comment: I creat a new xml file and i called xmlbanner.xml and i add the code of banner but what about the adview wher can i add it.can i add it to any file in the ''scr'' folder or in a specific file   :


    // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

The AdView can be added to any layout - it doesn't have to be named "main.xml". You just put their AdView xml inside any layout where you want an ad to appear.

Comment: I creat a new xml file and i called xmlbanner.xml and i add the code of banner but what about the adview wher can i add it.can i add it to any file in the ''scr'' folder or in a specific file   :


    // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
}

Comment: The AdRequest code would go in any Activity that is using a layout that contains the AdView xml tag. If you want the ad to load everytime the activity appears put the code in the onResume() method of the activity.

Comment: They say in the developer website that i can Add The Adview code in the ''Src'' FOLDER on Main_Activity.xml But i can't  find this file On my code that i work On

Comment: I've integrated several ad sdk's and they all use generic terms for filenames - because they did not write your app - you did. So when they say "Main_Activity.xml" what they really mean is the layout file (.xml) that is associated with the activity that is launched when your app starts. That .xml file should be in the /res/layout/ folder of your app.